# ASP.NET Web API Custom Role Provider GetRolesForUser Only Called Once

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, roleprovider

I am using a custom role provider with Web API. I use the `Authorize` attribute to specify which roles the user must have on each controller. I use Windows authentication, so the user doesn't need to log in explicitly. This is an internal API.

On pages making multiple AJAX calls, the first AJAX call succeeds. All the rest return a 401.

I put a break point in `GetRolesForUser` in my custom role provider. I am only seeing this method getting hit one time.

Is there a reason why only the first AJAX request is using my role provider?

Comment: An interesting side note is that this code works in IE because it appears IE limits the number of concurrent AJAX calls. Why would concurrent requests be causing the issue?

Comment: Explicitly setting `async: false` in `$.ajax` also fixes the issue, but isn't an ideal solution.